# "Margin-left" making fancybox narrow in Chrome

Tags: html, css, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-3

I'm using fancybox 3 to display a page (Page A) in an iframe. On a local server (running in Chrome) this worked great; however, online it does not - the iframe gets really narrow, and a quick inspection shows that Chrome registers fancybox-content width as 0. (It works fine in Safari.)

When I take "margin-left" styling out of one of the SVGs in Page A, the iframe appears normally again. However, this isn't a viable solution because Page A content doesn't display properly without the margin-left styling.

[Here](http://www.columbia.edu/~jeh2212/portfolio.html)'s the offending page; the box in question is the first one on the left ("Growing Bookshelves"). The page seen in the iframe is [here](http://www.columbia.edu/~jeh2212/testing/spec/book-slider.html).

Things I've already tried:

- [Change width and height of frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080964/fancybox-3-cant-override-width-and-height-of-iframe) based on this post and many,
  many others, using both CSS and JavaScript
- Changing various parts of Page A (tried to use
  "position:relative" and "left:xx%" instead of "margin-left", tried to
  put the svg in span/div; tried to change "display" style of body to
  block and inline-block)

I've spent way too long on this so any help is appreciated!

P.S. I know the code is ugly, and I'm probably not doing everything exactly as it should be done according to convention. Just trying to pull some things together.

Comment: Could you, please, grab the source code of v3.3 from here - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/PEqJvL - to see if it works better? Also, I think that your problem is more likely to be related to the floating elements. Try setting `overflow:hidden` to the parent.

Comment: Hi Janis - I'd tried setting overflow to hidden, but it blocked part of the page from being seen. Fixed by changing width of SVG - you're right in that overflow was the issue; just had to change width instead of hide overflow to make it render alright.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

CSS margins can make an svg/div/etc go beyond the 100% width. I changed the width of the SVG from 100% to 33% and just redrew the dimensions since it got smaller.